# SQL identifying Union

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep getting a Select error that a reserved word is either misspelled, or missing or the punctuation is incorrect but I cannot locate the source of this error. Some help is needed.

```
SELECT Style,
       Short,
       Color,
       [Logo 1],
       Forecast,
       COMMIT,
       Variance 
INTO ForecastvsCommitCombined
FROM
  (SELECT [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Style,
          [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Short,
          [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Color,
          [FanWalForecastVsCommit].[Logo 1],
          [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Forecast,
          [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Commit,
          [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Variance
   FROM [FanWalForecastVsCommit]
   UNION ALL SELECT [MeijerForecastVsCommit].Style,
                    [MeijerForecastVsCommit].Short,
                    [MeijerForecastVsCommit].Color,
                    [MeijerForecastVsCommit].[Logo 1], AS [MeijerForecastVsCommit].Forecast,
                    [MeijerForecastVsCommit].Commit,
                    [MeijerForecastVsCommit].Variance
   FROM [MeijerForecastVsCommit]
   UNION ALL SELECT [MidTierForecastVsCommit].Style,
                    [MidTierForecastVsCommit].Short,
                    [MidTierForecastVsCommit].Color,
                    [MidTierForecastVsCommit].[Logo 1],
                    [MidTierForecastVsCommit].Forecast,
                    [MidTierForecastVsCommit].Commit,
                    [MidTierForecastVsCommit].Variance
   FROM [MidTierForecastVsCommit]
   UNION ALL SELECT [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].Style,
                    [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].Short,
                    [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].Color,
                    [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].[Logo 1],
                    [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].Forecast,
                    [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].Commit,
                    [SamsClubForecastVsCommit].Variance
   FROM [SamsClubForecastVsCommit]
   UNION ALL SELECT [TargetForecastvsCommit].Style,
                    [TargetForecastvsCommit].Short,
                    [TargetForecastvsCommit].Color,
                    [TargetForecastvsCommit].[Logo 1],
                    [TargetForecastvsCommit].Forecast,
                    [TargetForecastvsCommit].Commit,
                    [TargetForecastvsCommit].Variance
   FROM [TargetForecastvsCommit]
   UNION ALL SELECT [WalmartForecastVsCommit].Style,
                    [WalmartForecastVsCommit].Short,
                    [WalmartForecastVsCommit].Color,
                    [WalmartForecastVsCommit].[Logo 1],
                    [WalmartForecastVsCommit].Forecast,
                    [WalmartForecastVsCommit].Commit,
                    [WalmartForecastVsCommit].Variance
   FROM [WalmartForecastVsCommit]);
```

Comment: I reformatted your code to make it readable. Please consider doing it yourself before your submit your next question. Huge unformatted queries are less likely to get proper looks from the Stack Overflow community...

Answer (score 1):

You are using reserved keyword `COMMIT` once at the beginning of the statement where it is not prefixed. You want to enclose that word in brackets (`[]`).

There are other occurences of the `COMMIT` word in the query, but as it is prefixed, it should not generate errors. If it does, consider using brackets as well.

```
SELECT Style,
   Short,
   Color,
   [Logo 1],
   Forecast,
   COMMIT, --> HERE : should be [COMMIT]
   Variance 
INTO ForecastvsCommitCombined
FROM
    (SELECT [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Style,
        [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Short,
        [FanWalForecastVsCommit].Color,
...
```

Comment: I change the column name to Current_Commmits for this and the subsequent queries and I am still getting the following error. I am not quite sure what else it could be

Comment: @Broady : OK, did you try to change also the other occurences of the `Commit` word ?

Comment: I did  Short is a reserved command as well that I had to change. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Commit!!! is a command and probably can not be use aa column name. You need to include the name with a as like as [commit]